# Redirecting to previous page after login in HTML (or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have been searching in a lot of places for answer to this.

What I want is when I go on a page, it redirects the page to the password page, but when I try to get it back, it just redirects back onto the previous page. Maybe use javascript to say "only redirect when there is a part in that code? Any ideas?

Comment: there are many different ways to do that. In javascript one way I see is roughly using something like `location.replace('url/to/your/loginpage')` on the password protected page for instance

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. I'll try to use that later. By the way, by `url/to/your/loginpage`, do you mean putting my url there?

Comment: Can't you just type in that url in the first place to skip the passworf